# Write Git pull command output in a file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am not able to write git pull command in a file. 
I have tried running these commands but of no help

```
git pull --all --dry-run >~/temp1
cat ~/temp1
```

output is just have a single line "Fetching origin" and rest of the output is dumped on the command line.
I have also tried

```
git pull --all --dry-run |tee -a ~/temp1
```

Kindly help me how to go about it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to the file, something like.

```
git pull --all --dry-run > ~/temp1 2>&1
```

- See [Bash Redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)

Comment: Or just this `&>`

Comment: I did not know.